# Find median of 2 sorted arrays with different lengths

Tags: algorithms, order-statistics, median

I'm trying to solve the below problem for my assignment but I have no clue how to find the time algorithm. If I have two arrays of same even length then I get, $T(n) = T(n/2) + \theta(n)$
but what about having $m$ and $n$ (not specified odd or even )?

Let $X[1 .. n]$ and $Y[1 .. m]$ be two arrays, containing n and m numbers respectively and they are already in sorted order. Give an $O(\log n + \log m)$ time algorithm to find the median of all $(n+m)$ elements in arrays $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  What you want is to find $p$ such that $X[\frac n2 + p]=Y[\frac m2 -p]$.  In the spirit of bisection, start with $p=0$.  If $X[\frac n2] \gt Y[\frac m2]$ you need to decrease $p$, while if $X[\frac n2] \lt Y[\frac m2]$ you need to increase $p$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean? Correct me if I understood wrong. So, I find the median of both arrays and then compare if X median larger than Y, I take X(median) - 1 , otherwise increase. But that is same algorithm I did for two n-sized array.

Comment: @newbieLinuxCpp:  It works the same.  Let's take $X$ to be the numbers $1-100$ and $Y$ to be the numbers $30.1-90.1$ that are $0.1$ more than a multiple of $3$ (so $21$) of them.  We check $X[50]=50$ and $Y[11]=60.1$ so we need to move up in $X$ and down in $Y$ by the same number of locations.  We will find $X[53]=53, Y[8]=51.1,Y[9]=54.1$, so the median is $53$.  You'll have to take larger steps than $1$ to get the $\log(n)$ behavior you want.  There are perturbations if you run out of the small array-take the same $X$ and $Y=101,102,103$.

Comment: @RossMillikan: I am sorry to ask this. Can you please explain how you arrived that median is 53 just by comparing [53]=53,[8]=51.1,[9]=54.1 Are you deciding based on the minimum difference between X[i] and Y[j]?

Comment: @Shashikant:  in this example there are $121$ numbers, so we want the $61$st largest.  We have that there are $61$ of them less than or equal to $53$, $53$ of them in $X$ and $8$ of them in $Y$.  I just see if we are too large or too small and move in the indicated drection.

Comment: @RossMillikan: If my understanding is correct, can we say that we have to find the `max([2+], [2−])` which will be the median? And for the case of where one array is quite smaller as you mentioned above, this will not work?

Comment: @Shashikant:  We need to find the value which has $\frac {n+m}2$ values above and below it.  If the medians of $X$ and $Y$ disagree we need a value above the $X$ median and below the $Y$ median by the same number of places, which is $p$.  No, there is no reason it won't work if the arrays are different sizes.  The example has one array $5$ times as large as the other.